# netmiko connections from device list is only connecting to first ip in list

Tags: netmiko

Im using
(base) C:\python
Python 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 15:08:03) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.sing

Created on Wed Jun 16 10:15:59 2021

```py
import logging
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

logging.basicConfig(filename='test2.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
    logger = logging.getLogger("netmiko")
    with open('host.txt', "r") as host:
    for ip in  host.read().splitlines():
        cisco = {
        'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
        'ip': ip,
        'username': 'user',
        'password': 'password', 
    }
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**cisco)
    print (' #### Connecting to ' + ip)
    output = net_connect.find_prompt()
    print(output)

    net_connect.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `for loop`. `Netmiko` accepts one dictionary within the `ConnectHandler` class. So to make the code run **"for each"** device, you have to create a loop.

Also, in the `for loop` you created to read the IP addresses from `hosts.txt`, you keep overwriting the `cisco` dict every time in the loop. `cisco = {}` overwrites the previous value each time. New values should be appended to a list instead.

You can achieve this by doing:

```py
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename="test2.log", level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger("netmiko")


with open(file="hosts.txt", mode="r") as hosts:
    # A list comprehension
    devices = [
        {
            "device_type": "cisco_ios",
            "ip": ip,
            "username": "cisco",
            "password": "cisco",
        }
        for ip in hosts.read().splitlines()
    ]

print(devices)  #  <--- print value is below

# Connect to each device (one at a time)
for device in devices:
    print(f'Connecting to {device["ip"]}')  # Here you are still trying to connect
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**device)
    print(f'Connected to {device["ip"]}')  # Here you are already connected
    prompt = net_connect.find_prompt()
    net_connect.disconnect()  # disconnect from the session

    # Finally, print the prompt within the foor loop, but
    # after you disconnect. You no longer need the connection to print.
    print(prompt)
```

You can forget about `net_connect.disconnect()` by using `with` statement *(Context Manager)*

> It's important to clear the vty line after you are done

```py
for device in devices:
    print(f'Connecting to {device["ip"]}')  # Here you are still waiting to connect
    with ConnectHandler(**device) as net_connect:
        print(f'Connected to {device["ip"]}')  # Here you are already logged-in
        prompt = net_connect.find_prompt()
    print(prompt)
```

If you print the `devices` list, you will get:

```sh
[{'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
  'ip': '192.168.1.1',  # From hosts.txt file
  'password': 'cisco',
  'username': 'cisco'},
 {'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
  'ip': '192.168.1.2',  # From hosts.txt file
  'password': 'cisco',
  'username': 'cisco'}]
```